# title attribute for element with pointer-events: none

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have this:

```
 <span ng-attr-title="{{isCustomerAndAssociationSetInSessStorage ? 'asdf' : 'Select association'}}">
        <a class="btn btn-app" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#developerdetailsmodel"
        ng-disabled="!isCustomerAndAssociationSetInSessStorage" ng-class="{'disableClass': !isCustomerAndAssociationSetInSessStorage}"
       data-whatever="@getbootstrap" ng-click="func();">
       <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add Developer Details
      </a>
 </span>
```

I have an anchor tag that I'm using as a button wrapped around a `span`. When `isCustomerAndAssociationSetInSessStorage` is false I add `.disableClass` using `ng-class`.

The `disableClass` has `pointer-events:none`. I want to show `title` when it is disabled. So I wrapped it around a `span`.

It shows the `asdf` title when there's no `disableClass` on `a` element. But when it has a `disableClass`, the title does not show the `'Select association'` in the else part of ternary operation above.

I inspect element and see the `title` attribute on the `span` but it does not show on hover.

Comment: Can not reproduce: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-wsa3r9

Comment: what is the value for isCustomerAndAssociationSetInSessStorage in else case whether false or null .Check it

Comment: @Justcode i had an inline style for the element which i removed while posting here. removed it in my code and it worked. thanks